# 16.04 - 'Colored Static-like noise around windows' problem after standby after Nvidia driver and/or kernel update (Screenshot attached)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, suspend

**Update**

With kernel 4.4.0-81 it seems to work well again, without myself doing anything extra to fix it.

---

Everything was working fine until a little more than a month ago, there were multiple kernel updates and Nvidia driver updates during that period so I'm not sure which one caused this problem.

I get the distortion below in the screen after starting the machine from standby (goes away if I restart/log out and log back in), it's shown around any window that is not maximized, around dialog boxes, around menus, basically around any edge on the screen.

I'm currently running kernel `4.4.0-77` and Nvidia driver from the package `nvidia-375`

[image: Sample image of problem]

PS: switching to the other driver causes other problems, and this one was working very well before this issue, and it had been running properly for months before this problem started happening.

Comment: @muru that is true yes, I wasn't able to find a similar thread when I posted because I'm using quite different wording to describe the problem, but it is the same problem actually. Should I delete it or what? I'm not aware of the correct action here.

Comment: mark it is a duplicate (you should have an option to do so at the top of the question), so people who searched for your wording can find the dupe